# How to list Jetstream Roles on other view blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I been searching all over the documentation and internet to find how to do it.

I can see that Jetstream has team-member-manager.php where you can set new members and assign roles to them. They can list this via this

```
<!-- Role -->
                    @if (count($this->roles) > 0)
                        <div class="col-span-6 lg:col-span-4">
                            <x-jet-label for="role" value="{{ __('Role') }}" />
                            <x-jet-input-error for="role" class="mt-2" />

                            <div class="mt-1 border border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
                                @foreach ($this->roles as $index => $role)
                                        <div class="px-4 py-3 {{ $index > 0 ? 'border-t border-gray-200' : '' }}"
                                                        wire:click="$set('addTeamMemberForm.role', '{{ $role->key }}')">
                                            <div class="{{ isset($addTeamMemberForm['role']) && $addTeamMemberForm['role'] !== $role->key ? 'opacity-50' : '' }}">
                                                <!-- Role Name -->
                                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 {{ $addTeamMemberForm['role'] == $role->key ? 'font-semibold' : '' }}">
                                                        {{ $role->name }}
                                                    </div>

                                                    @if ($addTeamMemberForm['role'] == $role->key)
                                                        <svg class="ml-2 h-5 w-5 text-green-400" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
                                                    @endif
                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Role Description -->
                                                <div class="mt-2 text-xs text-gray-600">
                                                    {{ $role->description }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
```

now I want use this kind of matter on other blade, but I can't seem to work how `$this->roles` coming from.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/1.x/src/Http/Livewire/TeamMemberManager.php) is the code powers the blade you wanted.

So as you can see that the code is where the magic happens, it's called dynamic property I think. This means when you have a method like this `getRolesProperty()` you can access it at the frontend like this `$this->roles`;

```php
    /**
     * Get the available team member roles.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRolesProperty()
    {
        return array_values(Jetstream::$roles);
    }
```

You can just copy the component and modify it for your need and then return your own view.